# Substitution encryption not returning characters

Tags: c++, encryption

I am currently attempting to make a substitution encryption/decryption program. This program reads from a file and encrypts character by character based on a user given key. For example, if the file reads "ATTACK AT DAWN" and the key given is "LEMON", the resulting cyphertext would be "LXFOPV EF RNHR".

I've made a function for encryption, however, it changes the values to characters other than alphanumeric letters. Any help would be appreciated. I've pasted the function below:

```
void encrypt(ifstream& in_s, ofstream& out_s, char next, char& cypher, int& i, char key[])
{

    in_s.get(next); // get character from file
    while (!in_s.eof())
    {
            check_i(i); // check i value is within the constraint for key[4]

            if(isupper(next)) // if uppercase run cypher
            {
                    cypher = ((next - 65) + (key[i] - 65) % 26) + 65;
            }
            else if (islower(next))
            {
                    next = toupper(next); // change to upper
                    cypher = ((next - 65) + (key[i] - 65) % 26) + 65;
                    cypher = tolower(cypher); // change to lower
            }
            else // if blank do nothing
            {
                    cypher = next;
            }
            cout << cypher;


            in_s.get(next); // get next char
            i++; // add 1 to i for key[i]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  The modulo operator `%` has a higher precedence than addition.  So let's break down your sum:

```
cypher = ((next - 65) + (key[i] - 65) % 26) + 65;
```

This will be processed like this:

```
cypher = ( next - 65 )
       + ( (key[i] - 65) % 26 )
       + 65;
```

What you actually wanted was for the modulo to act across the whole thing:

```
cypher = ( (next - 65 + key[i] - 65) % 26 ) + 65;
```

You don't actually need that outer set of parentheses, but it makes it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for the input. I've fixed that, however the "encrypted" characters are still not all alphanumeric. I'm thinking it might be something wrong with my key function.

Comment: It's hard to comment because you never showed the _actual_ output of your program and you didn't show the definition of the `check_i` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I was getting the input for my array.
I was attempting to do something like this:

```
cout << "Please enter a 5 character key: ";
cin >> key[5];
```

When I should have stored the array like this:

```
cout << "Please enter a 5 character key: ";
cin >> key;
```